# Application Context in multi module maven project - Spring

Tags: spring, maven-2, applicationcontext

I have a hard time understanding how application context work in multi module project.

Lets say I have a WAR Application "App". App has Jars A, B and C. A has a pom dependency on B and C has pom dependency on B. So can the beans defined in A be used in C as they are packaged in WAR file and are loaded at run time.

The application-context files of A, B and C are imported in WAR application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Here is why:

Simply because Spring is able to **scan the classpath** of the your application (if you are using the java annotation, `@ComponentScan('com')` will load every class you have in the package `com.**`).

If you are only running your JAR C with its dependencies, and you are loading every class in a particular package for instance, then you will be fine, you won't have any surprises.

The same if you do A and B.

But if you use A, B and C, and you have Spring scanning your packages (some common packages between A and C for instance), then you can have beans declared by A and beans declared by B. Which could some error if you thought you were having only one bean of type `Datasource`, by you have one in A and one in C.

Here is an example:

A has a DataSource.

```
package com.my.datasource;

@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationA() {
    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        //return new datasource...
    }
}
```

C has a DataSource.

```
package com.my.datasource;

@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationC() {
    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        //return new datasource...
    }
}
```

And B declared a JdbcTemplate :

```
package com.my.template;

@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationB() {
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate template(DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

If you run:
 - C + B -> 1 DataSource + 1 JdbcTemplate. OK !
 - A + B -> 1 DataSource + 1 JdbcTemplate. OK !
 - A + C + B -> -> 2 DataSources + 1 JdbcTemplate. KO !

This situation will happen if the WAR you deploy also has a `@ComponentScan("com.my")`.

So yes, it is possible to have access of bean defined in A in C, but this can be like hidden dependencies, you code is unclear, the execution is uncertain and could fail like succeed without you knowing what is going on.

Is it clearer ?